# Galois group over the field of rational functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am looking to find the Galois group of $x^3-x+t$ over $\mathbb{C}(t)$, the field of rational functions with complex coefficients. I have shown that the automorphisms of the rational function field $F(t)$ for fixed $F$ are precisely the fractional linear transformations that is $t \rightarrow \frac{at +b}{ct+d}$ for $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$. Is this useful? Also is there anyway to factor $x^3-x+t$ nicely?

I slept on this for a little bit and developed an idea to show this. I used Cardano's method to explicitly solve for the roots of this polynomial and show that there exist no linear factors in $\mathbb{C}(t)$ and $f(x)$ is therefore irreducible. This is because the polynomial is cubic, and if there are no linear factors then there cannot be any quadratic factors. Thus, you have to adjoin some root let's call it $\theta$ to $\mathbb{C}(t)$. The degree of this field over $\mathbb{C}(t)$ is a Galois extension and must have degree 3. The only group with order 3 is $\mathbb{Z}_3$, which implies this is the Galois group.

Comment: You can easily determine the Galois group of a cubic polynomial simply by computing its discriminant and deciding whether it is a square or not.

Comment: See www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/cubicquarticallchar.pdf

Comment: Ah because if the discriminant is square then the Galois group is isomorphic to $A_3$ and $S_3$ otherwise. Thank you!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thank you!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I offer an alternative solution, please take a look.

Comment: What you wrote is not correct. Your argument is, essentially, that as the polynomial is irreducible, adjoining one of its roots gives a normal extwnsion, and that is very false.

Comment: Chiming in with Mariano. Why do you get a Galois extension by adjoining $\theta$?

Comment: I see. I guess if anything I just showed an alternate way to show that the polynomial is irreducible. Thank you @JyrkiLahtonen and @Mariano!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Just wanted to clarify, does it not hold that since $f(x)$ is irreducible, if there is an extension that contains its root, then it must contain all of the roots of $f(x)$?

Comment: Consider the possibly more familiar case of the splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $\Bbb{Q}$. You can adjoin one of the roots, say $\alpha=\root3\of2$, but all the numbers in the field $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ are real, so the other zeros $\alpha(-1\pm i\sqrt3)/2$ are still not included. For some other polynomials the other zeros would be joined as well, but this is anything but automatic.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Weird, I just learned this in class: "Let $f(x)=x^3+px+q$ be irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$ snd $L=\Bbb Q(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$ be a splitting field of f with $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ roots of f. Then $Gal(L/\Bbb Q)\cong S_3$ if $\delta\notin \Bbb Q$, and $Gal(L/\Bbb Q)\cong A_3$ if $\delta\in \Bbb Q$, where $\delta^2=-4p^3-27q^2$ is the discriminant." Which looks like what OP wrote. But you said it's not true. Was I taught the wrong stuff?

Comment: @Divide1918 What you were taught is correct. Here $p=-1$ and $q=t$, so
$$\delta^2=-4p^3-27q^2=4-27t^2.$$ This is not the square of any element of $\Bbb{C}(t)$. Many ways to see that! Given that the cubic is also irreducible it follows that  the Galois group is $S_3$.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I don't see how to use Eisenstein here. But the polynomial is a cubic, so if it factors, then one of the factors is linear, and the polynomial would have a zero $x=\frac{p(t)}{q(t)}\in\Bbb{C}(t)$ with some polynomials $p(t),q(t)\in\Bbb{C}[t]$, $q\neq0$.

To exclude this possibility we use a line of reasoning analogous to the familiar rational root test - taking advantage of the fact that $\Bbb{C}[t]$ is a UFD. So assume that all common factors of $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ have been cancelled. Then
$$
x^3-x+t=\frac{p^3-pq^2+tq^3}{q^3}=0.
$$
Here the numerator has to be zero, so from
$$
p^3-pq^2=-tq^3
$$
we can conclude that $p$ divides the left hand side, hence also the right hand side. But $p$ has no common factors with $q$, so it has to be a factor of $t$.

Similarly from
$$
p^3=pq^2-tq^3
$$
we see that $q$ divides the right hand side, hence also $p^3$. But, as above, this implies that $q$ must be a constant.

The non-zero constants are the units of $\Bbb{C}[t]$, so we can conclude that $x=p/q$ is either a constant or, $x=at$ for some $a\in\Bbb{C}$.

I'm sure that you can show that neither of those work. Therefore this cubic has no linear factors over $\Bbb{C}(t)$ and hence it is irreducible.

Comment: thank you for your help. I offer an alternative solution, do you see any problems with it?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Show that the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb C[t]$ (which shows irreducibility over $\mathbb C(t)$ by Gauss) and then compute the discriminant as usual.

Comment: I know showing irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$ can be done using Eisenstein's Criterion. Is there a similar trick for $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Eisenstein's criterion works over the field of fractions of a UFD, such as $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb C[t]$.

Comment: After substituting $x+a$ for some integer $a$, I believe then I will be able to show the polynomial to satisfy Eisenstein's critertion. Thank you @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez and @Mesih!

Comment: By Gauss, irreducibility in $\mathbf C(T)[X]$ is (essentially) equivalent to irreducibility in $\mathbf C[T,X]$, which (here) follows from the fact that the degree in $T$ is $1$.