# Galois group of a polynomial over $\mathbb C(t)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I am learning for my exam tomorrow and I am facing the following task:

Compute the Galois group of $x^3-2tx+t$ over $\mathbb C(t)$

At first I want to show that this polynomial is indeed irreducible. And it is sufficient if I am able to show that there are no roots. But thb I am not able to handle polynomials like this...

Can someone give ma a tip?

Comment: Hint: try Eisenstein's criterion. (If you are stuck on showing that $\langle t \rangle$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{C}(t)$, consider $\mathbb{C}(t)/\langle t \rangle$.)

Comment: Do we have $\mathbb C(t)/<t>\cong \mathbb C$?

Comment: Duke: yes. (Why? :) I can help more if you don't understand this point.)

Comment: Just intuitively: in $\mathbb C(t)$ we have elements of the form $a+bt$ and if I ignore "t", then we have just elements of the form $a$ with $a$ being a complex number :D. Technically I have to find a homomorphism from $\mathbb C(t)$ to $\mathbb C$ such that $<t>$ generates the kernel. Than I could conclude the statement with the homomorphism theorem. But I was not able to find such homomorphism, can you help? And can you correct me if some of my thoughts are wrong? Edit: If $<p>$ is a prime ideal, then $p$ is a prime, correct? So we can apply Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: @AlexWertheim $\mathbb{C}(t)$ is a field, hence has no nontrivial ideals.

Comment: @SpamIAm: yes, I should have said $\mathbb{C}[t]$, where it is sufficient to show irreducibility by Gauss' lemma, I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$\mathbb{C}[t] / (t)$ is indeed isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, look at the definition:
The qoutient are the rest when you divide through the polynomials without constant term.

In case you want to find the homomorphism: Try
$\mathbb{C}(t) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, f(t) \mapsto f(0)$, the kernel is exactly the ideal $(t)$ and the map is surjective. Then it's just the homomorphism theorem.

After this: Do you know how to compute the Discriminant of a polynomial with degree 3?

Comment: Yes, the rest is totally clear to me :). Question: Does this similar work if we consider the polynomial $x^3-x+t$?

Comment: With this polynomial Eisenstein doesn't apply this easily, so it's not clear why it should be irreducible.

Comment: I got this polynomial from this thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153750/galois-group-over-the-field-of-rational-functions   . But I don't understand why it is irreducible

Comment: In the thread they talk about a transformation $x \mapsto x+a$, but I don't see how this can work

Comment: Yeah, me either. But I got a question. I can't see why $<t>$ lies in the kernel of your homomorphism above. Could you explain it for me?

Comment: @Duke: You can see $\langle t \rangle \subset \ker f$, since any element $h(t) \in \langle t \rangle$ can be written $tg(t)$ for $g(t) \in \mathbb{C}[t]$, whence $h(0) = 0\cdot g(0) = 0$. To see $\ker f \subset \langle t \rangle$, note that $\mathbb{C}[t]$ is a Euclidean domain, so you can apply division by $t$.

Comment: +1 to ben @Duke: I think that the irreducibility of $x^3-x+t$ is best settled using the analogue of the rational root test (as opposed to the analogue of Eisenstein). I added such an answer to the linked question.